# Include source files generated by prebuild-event

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, flatbuffers, pre-build-event

I want to generate C# classes from a flatbuffer schema, and consume these classes in another project.

For this I need to invoke the flatbuffer schema compiler to generate the classes. I do not want to check in the class-files, but rather generate them during the build process, such that I do not need to update them manually.

Assume a C# solution with two projects:

```
MessageDefinitions.csproj
MessageConsumer.csproj
```

MessageDefinitions contains a prebuild event, which invokes the flatbuffer schema compiler and puts the generated C# source files into the folder *MessageDefinitions/Messages/*.

I then want to consume the generated types in MessageConsumer (which has a reference to MessageDefinitions).

The problem is that the compiled MessageDefinitions.dll does not contain the generated types, and thus building MessageConsumer fails.
If I compile a second time, the build succeeds, as the files in *MessageDefinitions/Messages/* already exist and are included in the compiled output.

Is there a way to make the compiler include the source files generated by the prebuild-event in MessageDefinitions on the first build?

Any help is appreciated,
Kind regards.

Comment: You should consider putting the generated file in a sub folder called gen in your project

Comment: From past experience I can suggest this, create a dummy empty project in your solution called e.g. BeforeBuildEvents that is the first project to build in your solution then move the Pre-Build events from your project to this project. That helped my in the pass to solve similar issues with pre-build events

Comment: Chicken-and-egg problem.  It will run the prebuild event only *after* determining what needs to be built and whether a build is necessary at all.  You can only get a helpful answer when you explain why such shenanigans were deemed necessary.

Comment: genuine question, sorry if this sounds silly - why not just `<Compile Include="../Class1.cs" />` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I simplified my real project for this post, probably a bit too much. "Class1.cs" represents an autogenerated flatbuffer message definition generated during the prebuild-event by invoking the flatbuffer schema compiler. So, it does not actually copied but created during the event.

Comment: @DanielA.White
Would a sub-folder named "gen" be treated differently by the compiler?
The output of the prebuild-event is already placed into a subfolder of the MyProject-folder.

Comment: @Siraf If I understand your proposal correctly, this is what I did. The problem is that the compiled dummy project will not contain the files generated during the prebuild event, and thus they cannot be consumed by dependent projects.

Comment: @HansPassant This explains why my attempt does not work. I was hoping for something like a compiler flag that would enable this behavior, but could not find a suitable option in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add something like the following to `MessageDefinitions.csproj`. I adapted and simplified it from the gist [AddGeneratedFile.csproj](https://gist.github.com/KirillOsenkov/f20cb84d37a89b01db63f8aafe03f19b) by the [author](https://gist.github.com/KirillOsenkov) of [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) (a tool a strongly recommend taking advantage of when working with MSBuild).

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MessageClassesPath>MessageDefinitions/Messages/**/*.cs</MessageClassesPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AddMessageClasses" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile;CoreCompile">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="$(MessageClassesPath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: There's a missing '>' after the opening PropertyGroup tag, but I can't edit:)

Comment: Even though this is 10 years old, it helped me out today, thank you so much good sir

Comment: It’s 2 months old lol :). Glad it was useful to you, @Foitn!

Comment: @weir, oh lol indeed, guess I saw Oct 12 and thought october 2012  Well thanks anyway